# Laravel wkhtmltopdf pdf generation timeout

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to generate pdf in laravel using **wemersonjanuario/laravelpdf**.
Below is my controller function.

```
public function generate_pdf($table,$all_data)
{
    $pdf_name = $version.'_'.$table.'.pdf';
    File::delete('directory/'.$pdf_name);
    $view = \View::make('pdf',['all_data'=>$all_data]);
    PDF::loadHTML($view)->orientation('Landscape')
        ->save($pdf_name , new Local(base_path().'/public/'));
    return '/public/'.$pdf_name ;
}
```

Here,

> $all_data = Data I have fetched from my table
>
> $view = View that I rendered from the data
>
> $table = Table name

After generating the pdf I return the saved path to javascript to open the path using window.open.

Here is the blade area

```
    @php($page = 1)
    @foreach ($all_data['p_datas'] as $key => $cols)
    <section class="col-lg-12" style="width: {{$line_size}}px;page-break-before: always" >
        <table class='mytable'  style="border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <thead style="border-top:1px solid #000000;border-bottom: 1px solid #000000; text-align: center">
                <tr class='top-border bottom-border top'>
                @foreach ($all_data['columns'][$p_no] as $col)
                    <td class="text-center formate" style="width:{{$all_data['column_width'][$col]}}px; padding-right: {{ $all_data['td_space' ]}}px">{!! $col !!}</td>
                @endforeach
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody style="text-align: center;">
            @foreach($cols as $i=>$data)
            <tr>
                @foreach($data as $j=>$dt)
                    <td style="min-height: 40px;padding-bottom: 8px"> {!! $dt !!} </td>
                @endforeach
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="footnote col-sm-12" style="border-top: solid 1px;">
        <span class="footnote" id="footnote">{!!$footnote!!}</span>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <table class="row" style="margin-left: 30px">
            <tbody>
                <td style="width: 400px"><h6>Printed By: {{ $user }}</h6></td>
                <td style="width: 300px"><h6> Page <span> {{ $page }}</span></h6></td>
                <td style="width: 400px"><h6>Print Date : {{ $date }}</h6></td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>

    @php($page++)
@endforeach
```

In the table I have 1000 rows. In the blade file I run the loop for every 25 rows I break per page and render data.

If I only render the view in html using below code it takes highest 10 seconds. But when I try to generate the pdf it is taking a day or more. What is the problem here?

> $html = $view->render();
>
> return $html

I have used dompdf and tcpdf also but those appeared same as wkhtmltopdf. Is there any solution?

Comment: can you try saving the html to a file and running the wkhtmltopdf on the file? In general generating PDF using wkhtmltopdf usally takes time but a day seems like too much.

Comment: I am already doing it by PDF::loadHTML($view)->orientation('Landscape')
        ->save($pdf_name , new Local(base_path().'/public/')); here $view is the rendered html. isn't it?